# Firefox notificationbox onclose?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

How can I detect when a firefox xul notificationbox element I created is closed?

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this is what you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/notificationbox#p-notificationsHidden): Either the `notificationsHidden` property or the events that are right below it.

Comment: I tried attaching an AlertClose event before, however nothing fired. Have these events actually worked for you?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try it, I just tried to find something on the wiki that matched what you described.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can be sure is to create a derived binding for your notification in which case your destructor will run when the notification is closed. See for instance http://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/annotate/edc24697f35e/suite/common/bindings/notification.xml#l1616